# JSON decode - decode shopping cart PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel

Hi I'm working in Laravel 5.4. I save my cart to the database with json_encode, this is no problem. My problem is getting the data that i want in my view. I want to show for example the title and the price of the product.

I tried:

```
  @foreach ($order->cart->items as $item)
         {{ dd(json_decode($order->cart, true)) }}
        {{ $item['price']['title'] }}
   @endforeach
```

This is when i get the next error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

when i dump my cart

```
dd(json_decode($order->cart, true))
```

I get:

```
array:3 [▼
  "items" => array:1 [▼
    5 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 5
      "qty" => 1
      "price" => 15
      "item" => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "created_at" => "2017-06-05 13:21:45"
        "updated_at" => "2017-06-05 13:21:45"
        "imagePath" => "https://someImage"
        "title" => "Vitamin B-12"
        "discription" => "Vitamin B-12, also called cobalamin ▶"
        "category" => 4
        "price" => 15
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "totalQty" => 1
  "totalPrice" => 15
]
```

Comment: `$item["items"][5]["price"]["title"]` is the structure of you array here.

Comment: It's not `$order->cart->items` its `$order->cart->items()`, items is a function

Comment: @apOKRYFOS same error..

Answer (score 0):

Your `$order->cart` is an array not an object.
Try this:

```
<?php $data = json_decode($order->cart, true); ?>
@foreach ($data['items'] as $item)
    {{ $item['item']['title'] }} {{ $item['item']['price'] }}
@endforeach
```